# Plone + Ploneboard max upload file size

Tags: plone, zope, archetypes

I am trying to tune/implement max conversation attachment upload file size for Plone 4.1 and Ploneboard.

The code processing the uploads seems to be this in PloneBoard:

```
    # Create files in message
    if files:
        for file in files:
            # Get raw filedata, not persistent object with reference to tempstorage
            # file.data might in fact be OFS.Image.Pdata - str will piece it all together
            attachment = File(file.getId(), file.title_or_id(), str(file.data), file.getContentType())
            m.addAttachment(attachment)
```

Where and how uploaded filesizes are adjusted in Plone, Zope and Ploneboard?

Comment: AHA. Looks like this one was controlled in PloneBoard forum Edit page settings directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this one was controlled in PloneBoard forum Edit page settings directly.